# Wordpress: Alternative to wp_get_sidebars_widgets for theme development

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

`wp_get_sidebars_widgets()` is very usefull to get infos about widgets in a sidebar. However, the WP codex states it's a private function, not to be used for theme development... which is specifically my case. What are the alternatives? How to get widgets infos without it? I guess with `dynamic_sidebar()` and some PHP but I don't see how, really.

What I want to get is:

- the widgets ids (which informs me what widget has been used).
- the widgets data entered by the user in the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution, but it looks like a hack. If someone knows something better...

My sidebar's id is 'homepage' and all my widget ids start with my prefix, `nd_home_`:

```
global $wp_registered_sidebars, $wp_registered_widgets;

ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar('homepage'); //my sidebar id is 'homepage'
$sidebar_contents = ob_get_clean();

$widgetidspart1 = explode('nd_home_',$sidebar_contents); //my widgets ids start with nd_home_
for ($i = 1; $i < count($widgetidspart1); $i++) {
    $widgetidspart2 = explode('" ', $widgetidspart1[$i] );
    $widgetids[] = $widgetidspart2[0]; //id without nd_home_
}

//add nd_home_ to every widget id
foreach ( $widgetids as $id) {
    $widgetids_total[] = 'nd_home_' . $id;
}

//now I have all the ids in $widgetids_total. I can get the widget data:

foreach( $widgetids_total as $id ) {

    $option_name = $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['callback'][0]->option_name;

    $key = $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['params'][0]['number'];
    $widget_data = get_option($option_name);

    $data[] = $widget_data[$key];
}

//$data contains my widgets data
```